# Installation of MSVC++ 2015 x86 Redistributable

Tags: installation, vcredist

When installation the MSVC++ 2015 x86 Redistributable (14.0.23026), the size of the library shows 1.92 MB.

On a second computer, the size for the same library is 20.7 MB.

I assume this explains the problem on the first computer to run dependent program.

I have uninstalled and installed a number of times, but to no avail.

Any idea how to make a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

This redist would install, but there was no warning, only the trained eye would see that the Setup Process did not behave properly.

Later only the small size of the redist in Add/Remove gave an indication.

The Microsoft application "Fix it" removed the remains from earlier installations.

Then it was possible to install the redist properly.